# CXF (and interceptors) and 2.5 webapps

Tags: servlets, weblogic, cxf, interceptor

I've a very basic question. When and How will CXF kick in if my webapp is 2.5 or higher. The weblogic 10.3 that I'm running picks up the WS annotation defined in my web-app.

Until now I had web-app version 2.3. When I upgraded it to 2.5 in webapp XML, I noticed my interceptors are not getting kicked in because now weblogic is able to handle the annotation and CXF is out of picture (based upon stacktrace analysis).

Is my observation correct, or am I totally wrong? I just changed from:

```
<DOCTYPE web-app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
```

to

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt want to mess with WL as we have more than one app running on the WL.So the simple solution was to use the handlers. See here: [handlers_introduction](https://jax-ws.java.net/articles/handlers_introduction.html).

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself clear but weblogic-application.xml is a config file inside EAR archive. Using it you can change classloading policy on application level, not server level. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, I know you are/were absolutely right. We have a JBoss migration schedule next year, I didn't want to increase my list of tasks for next year. But I do agree with what you said.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, changing Servlet version to 2.5 triggers autodiscovery of classes annotated with @WebService annotation.

To prevent this you have to tweak classloading policy. On Apache CXF site there is a good description: [Apache CXF - WebLogic](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html#ApplicationServerSpecificConfigurationGuide-WebLogic)

According to this website you have two options:

- "Put the geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.1.jar in the $Weblogic_Home/jdk_../jre/lib/endorsed folder." - this will affect whole server and might break other web services running on WebLogic
- "Pack war in an ear, deploy the ear with weblogic-application.xml" - this way you change classloading policy for single EAR application, not for whole server.

I prefer to use solution based on weblogic-application.xml, as it is more portable.

However it didn't work for me immediately, I had to add additional library to EAR/WAR - geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.1.jar.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't have yet EAR archive you have to create one. Assuming you are using maven:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=ear-jee5
```

And add your WAR project to dependencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for confirming my doubt.